# Execution Error when Writing in a hive 3 managed table by HWC

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hdfs, hdp

I'm developing a spark test application that read an external hive table perform some transformation and write to a hive managed table using Hive wharehouse connector to test the connection between spark and hive 3.

The application read the table by hwc but when it begin the insertion it crash with the following error

```
llap.HiveWarehouseDataSourceWriter - HiveWarehouseDataSourceWriter: com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseDataSourceWriter@6b6ddc37, msg:Committed File /tmp/20200304150515-003d4c58-e824-40fa-bac6-12ea92a36464/20200304150515-003d4c58-e824-40fa-bac6-12ea92a36464_39_0
2020-03-04 15:06:30.064 [main] INFO  llap.HiveWarehouseDataSourceWriter - Handling write: database:von_onogoro, table:mtm_reconciliation, savemode: Overwrite, tableExists:true, createTable:false, loadData:true
2020-03-04 15:06:30.072 [main] INFO  llap.HiveWarehouseDataSourceWriter - Load data query: LOAD DATA INPATH '/tmp/20200304150515-003d4c58-e824-40fa-bac6-12ea92a36464' OVERWRITE  INTO TABLE von_onogoro.mtm_reconciliation
2020-03-04 15:06:30.472 [main] INFO  llap.HiveWarehouseDataSourceWriter - Commit job 20200304150515-003d4c58-e824-40fa-bac6-12ea92a36464
2020-03-04 15:06:30.475 [main] ERROR llap.HiveWarehouseDataSourceWriter - Aborted DataWriter job 20200304150515-003d4c58-e824-40fa-bac6-12ea92a36464
2020-03-04 15:06:30.481 [main] ERROR processing.SpringTaskProcessor - Erreur fatale
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Writing job aborted.
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.doExecute(WriteToDataSourceV2.scala:112) ~[spark-sql_2.11-2.3.2.3.1.5.0-152.jar:2.3.2.3.1.5.0-152]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131) ~[spark-sql_2.11-2.3.2.3.1.5.0-152.jar:2.3.2.3.1.5.0-152]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127) ~[spark-sql_2.11-2.3.2.3.1.5.0-152.jar:2.3.2.3.1.5.0-152]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155) ~[spark-sql_2.11-2.3.2.3.1.5.0-152.jar:2.3.2.3.1.5.0-152]
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.3.2.3.1.5.0-152.jar:2.3.2.3.1.5.0-152]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152) ~[spark-sql_2.11-2.3.2.3.1.5.0-152.jar:2.3.2.3.1.5.0-152]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127) ~[spark-sql_2.11-2.3.2.3.1.5.0-152.jar:2.3.2.3.1.5.0-152]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80) ~[spark-sql_2.11-2.3.2.3.1.5.0-152.jar:2.3.2.3.1.5.0-152]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80) ~[spark-sql_2.11-2.3.2.3.1.5.0-152.jar:2.3.2.3.1.5.0-152]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:664) ~[spark-sql_2.11-2.3.2.3.1.5.0-152.jar:2.3.2.3.1.5.0-152]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:664) ~[spark-sql_2.11-2.3.2.3.1.5.0-152.jar:2.3.2.3.1.5.0-152]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77) ~[spark-sql_2.11-2.3.2.3.1.5.0-152.jar:2.3.2.3.1.5.0-152]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:664) ~[spark-sql_2.11-2.3.2.3.1.5.0-152.jar:2.3.2.3.1.5.0-152]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:256) ~[spark-sql_2.11-2.3.2.3.1.5.0-152.jar:2.3.2.3.1.5.0-152]
        at com.test.sparkHive.computation.reconciliation.mtm.dao.MtmReconciliationDao.saveIntoHive(MtmReconciliationDao.scala:85) ~[onogoro-computation_2.11-1.12.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.test.sparkHive.computation.reconciliation.mtm.MtmReconciliationFeeder.computeAndFeedMtmReconciliation(MtmReconciliationFeeder.scala:122) ~[onogoro-computation_2.11-1.12.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.test.sparkHive.reconciliation.mtm.MtmReconciliationProcessor.run(MtmReconciliationProcessor.java:46) ~[onogoro-1.12.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.sparkHive.common.processing.SpringTaskProcessor.start(SpringTaskProcessor.java:154) [common-econometrics-core-3.15.29.jar:?]
        at com.sparkHive.common.processing.SpringTaskProcessor.start(SpringTaskProcessor.java:118) [common-econometrics-core-3.15.29.jar:?]
        at com.test.sparkHive.reconciliation.mtm.MtmReconciliationProcessor.main(MtmReconciliationProcessor.java:40) [onogoro-1.12.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52) [spark-core_2.11-2.3.2.3.1.5.0-152.jar:2.3.2.3.1.5.0-152]
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:900) [spark-core_2.11-2.3.2.3.1.5.0-152.jar:2.3.2.3.1.5.0-152]
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:192) [spark-core_2.11-2.3.2.3.1.5.0-152.jar:2.3.2.3.1.5.0-152]
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:217) [spark-core_2.11-2.3.2.3.1.5.0-152.jar:2.3.2.3.1.5.0-152]
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:137) [spark-core_2.11-2.3.2.3.1.5.0-152.jar:2.3.2.3.1.5.0-152]
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala) [spark-core_2.11-2.3.2.3.1.5.0-152.jar:2.3.2.3.1.5.0-152]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MoveTask. org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Load Data failed for hdfs://hdfs-prince/tmp/20200304150515-003d4c58-e824-40fa-bac6-12ea92a36464/20200304150515-003d4c58-e824-40fa-bac6-12ea92a36464_0_0 as the file is not owned by hive and load data is also not ran as hive
        at com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseDataSourceWriter.commit(HiveWarehouseDataSourceWriter.java:172) ~[hive-warehouse-connector-assembly-1.0.0.3.1.5.0-152.jar:1.0.0.3.1.5.0-152]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.doExecute(WriteToDataSourceV2.scala:91) ~[spark-sql_2.11-2.3.2.3.1.5.0-152.jar:2.3.2.3.1.5.0-152]
        ... 29 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MoveTask. org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Load Data failed for hdfs://hdfs-prince/tmp/20200304150515-003d4c58-e824-40fa-bac6-12ea92a36464/20200304150515-003d4c58-e824-40fa-bac6-12ea92a36464_0_0 as the file is not owned by hive and load data is also not ran as hive
        at shadehive.org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.waitForOperationToComplete(HiveStatement.java:401) ~[hive-warehouse-connector-assembly-1.0.0.3.1.5.0-152.jar:1.0.0.3.1.5.0-152]
        at shadehive.org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:266) ~[hive-warehouse-connector-assembly-1.0.0.3.1.5.0-152.jar:1.0.0.3.1.5.0-152]
        at shadehive.org.apache.hive.jdbc.HivePreparedStatement.execute(HivePreparedStatement.java:101) ~[hive-warehouse-connector-assembly-1.0.0.3.1.5.0-152.jar:1.0.0.3.1.5.0-152]
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:94) ~[hive-warehouse-connector-assembly-1.0.0.3.1.5.0-152.jar:1.0.0.3.1.5.0-152]
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:94) ~[hive-warehouse-connector-assembly-1.0.0.3.1.5.0-152.jar:1.0.0.3.1.5.0-152]
        at com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.JDBCWrapper.executeUpdate(HS2JDBCWrapper.scala:356) ~[hive-warehouse-connector-assembly-1.0.0.3.1.5.0-152.jar:1.0.0.3.1.5.0-152]
        at com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.DefaultJDBCWrapper.executeUpdate(HS2JDBCWrapper.scala) ~[hive-warehouse-connector-assembly-1.0.0.3.1.5.0-152.jar:1.0.0.3.1.5.0-152]
        at com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseDataSourceWriter.handleWriteWithSaveMode(HiveWarehouseDataSourceWriter.java:276) ~[hive-warehouse-connector-assembly-1.0.0.3.1.5.0-152.jar:1.0.0.3.1.5.0-152]
        at com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseDataSourceWriter.commit(HiveWarehouseDataSourceWriter.java:170) ~[hive-warehouse-connector-assembly-1.0.0.3.1.5.0-152.jar:1.0.0.3.1.5.0-152]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.doExecute(WriteToDataSourceV2.scala:91) ~[spark-sql_2.11-2.3.2.3.1.5.0-152.jar:2.3.2.3.1.5.0-152]
        ... 29 more
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Writing job aborted.
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.doExecute(WriteToDataSourceV2.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:664)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:664)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:664)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:256)
        at com.test.sparkHive.computation.reconciliation.mtm.dao.MtmReconciliationDao.saveIntoHive(MtmReconciliationDao.scala:85)
        at com.test.sparkHive.computation.reconciliation.mtm.MtmReconciliationFeeder.computeAndFeedMtmReconciliation(MtmReconciliationFeeder.scala:122)
        at com.test.sparkHive.reconciliation.mtm.MtmReconciliationProcessor.run(MtmReconciliationProcessor.java:46)
        at com.sparkHive.common.processing.SpringTaskProcessor.start(SpringTaskProcessor.java:154)
        at com.sparkHive.common.processing.SpringTaskProcessor.start(SpringTaskProcessor.java:118)
        at com.test.sparkHive.reconciliation.mtm.MtmReconciliationProcessor.main(MtmReconciliationProcessor.java:40)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:900)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:192)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:217)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:137)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MoveTask. org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Load Data failed for hdfs://hdfs-prince/tmp/20200304150515-003d4c58-e824-40fa-bac6-12ea92a36464/20200304150515-003d4c58-e824-40fa-bac6-12ea92a36464_0_0 as the file is not owned by hive and load data is also not ran as hive
        at com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseDataSourceWriter.commit(HiveWarehouseDataSourceWriter.java:172)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.doExecute(WriteToDataSourceV2.scala:91)
        ... 29 more
```

The code to write in hive 3:

```
val hiveHwc=
com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseBuilder.session(spark).build()
  reconciliatinDF.write.format("com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseConnector")
              .option("database", "von_onogoro")
                .option("table", "mtm_reconciliation")
                    .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
                      .save()
```

Comment: i fixed the problem by put my applicative user in the hive propety hive.load.data.owner

Answer (score 1):

@Prince this error is a permissions issue:

> the file is not owned by hive and load data is also not ran as hive

If you address the permission issue, your query will complete.  If you have HDP, you should be able to use Ranger with Hive Plugin to create a policy for your spark user to have permissions for hive.